# setting up IDE for contributing in open source apache lucene

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, solr, lucene

I am a newbie in contributing to open source projects and this is my first one.

Apache Lucene Core

I downloaded its source code from the trunk of the project through apache subversion.

I was able to build it using ant through command line.

But i don't know how to set up Eclipse IDE and neither I found any proper information about it on the following URL:

[How to configure Eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToConfigureEclipse)

Kindly please help and let me know how should I continue further.

Comment: Drop Eclipse and use IntelliJ ;) On a more serious note, Lucene is a complicated piece of software... are you sure you'll be able to contribute anything meaningful to it? I mean setting up your IDE is a trivial task compared to tweaking Lucene...

Comment: Did you check this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629669